# Will android studio work faster with dedicated graphical card ? (AMD)

Tags: android, graphics, android-emulator

I have laptop with integrated intel graphic card and dedicated amd 2gb card. My question is will my laptop switch to dedicated card when i'm using android studio or emulator or do i need to set it manually? Will it work faster with dedicated card?

Comment: it will use the better graphics if any available. So your AMD card will be used automatically.

Comment: Good news is that Android Studio 3.0 (now is beta version) will radically speed up the build process.